# Como funciona as versões do APP android?

Tags: android, app

Gostaria de saber se a versão do APP Android sou eu que defino no XML pelo `TextView` mesmo, ou tem algo que tem que fazer para gerar aquele número.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É você quem define o número de versão do seu aplicativo. No arquivo **AndroidManifest.xml**, na própria tag `<manifest>` tem as propriedades `android:versionCode` e `android:versionName`. Sempre que você enviar uma nova versão do seu aplicativo para ser publicado na **Play Store** você precisa alterar estes valores.

O `android:versionCode` é um número inteiro qualquer mas você precisa ter certeza que a cada versão este número será maior do que a versão anterior. Normalmente começamos com o número 1 e vai incrementando a cada nova versão. Este valor não é mostrado para o usuário na loja.

Já o `android:versionName` é uma *string* que representa a versão do seu aplicativo e que será exibido para o usuário na loja.

Tem uma **[documentação](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)** que descreve melhor estas duas propriedades e até mesmo recomendações de como utilizá-las. Caso queira exibir dentro do seu aplicativo o nome da versão para o seu usuário em um `TextView` como você mencionou, é possível utilizar o código abaixo para obter este valor:

```
String versionName = null;

try {
    versionName = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito :) .